# H2, JPA2, JBoss AS 7 and Transactions

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, jboss7.x, h2

I have a test that runs perfectly when I use a MySQL Backend.

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="pu">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/mysqlTM</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />

        <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

However, when I switch to H2 as follows:

persistence.xml

```
    <persistence-unit name="pu">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

using the standard datasource as defined in the stock JBoss 7.1 install and I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
```

Google has been of little help. I would prefer to use H2 for testing merely to speed up the testing process.

Thanks in advance for any assistance,

Comment: could you post the code resulting in the exception, including the lines that you use to acquire the EntityManager?. BTW - you should not need `provider` and `dialect` attributes from the H2 persistence unit.

Comment: @kostja you led me down the right path. The code related to seam-security and I wanted to create a simple test case and even with injecting the seam transaction manager, it worked. I then realised that this was because of the different ways in which MySQL and H2 handle case sensitivity in queries. Thank you. :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question so it can be closed.

As it turns out, the error message with regards to transactions is a red-herring. The error was caused due to the different ways in which MySQL and H2 handle case sensitivity in queries.

Updating the queries to be case sensitive solved the issue.